# Liferay 6.2 ajax portlet content rendering

Tags: ajax, liferay

I've noticed that sometimes liferay loads the content of a portlet using ajax. For example, we've done some heavy duty web content templates and sometimes I can see a loading spinner while rendering the page.

I know about ajaxable and render-weight properties in liferay-portlet.xml, but... how does liferay know whether to render a portlet content using ajax or not? and second question, is it any way to disable this feature for asset publisher and web content display portlets without changing liferay's internal liferay-portlet.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default ajaxable is set to true.
In order to modify this you can try updating the render-weight and ajaxable attributes using the class PortletPreferences.
Read more here: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/11904281